# this.value returns undefined on a td value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the value of a specific  within a table. Using the following jQuery:

```
$( 'td.calendar-day' ).click(function() {
console.log(this);
```

Returns

```
<td class="calendar-day" value="2014-01-03">
<div class="day-number">3</div>
<div class="class"><a href="http://website.com" target="_blank">2</a></div>
<div class="class"><a href="http://website.com" target="_blank">2</a></div>
<div class="class"><a href="http://website.com" target="_blank">2</a></div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</td>
```

When I click on the following cell

```
<td class="calendar-day" value="2014-01-03">
```

However when I add:

```
console.log(this.value);
```

It returns: `undefined`

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: $(this).attr('value');

Comment: A table row isn't supposed to have a value attribute.

Comment: Or `this.getAttribute('value');`. That way you don't have to turn `this` into a jQuery object if you are using it for nothing else.

Comment: Use data attributes like @dcodesmith did in his answer. With jQuery you can also use data easily. `$('.class').data('value')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
 $( 'td.calendar-day' ).click(function() {
   console.log($(this).attr('value'));
});
```

Comment: @bhooks This might "work" but it's hardly the best solution. No offense to Nouphal.M.

Answer (score 8):

Use the data-* attribute. A table row isn't supposed to have a value attribute. Best practise would be to set a data attribute and then grab it

**HTML**

```
<td class="calendar-day" data-value="2014-01-03">
```

**Js**

```
$('td.calendar-day').click(function() {
    this.getAttribute('data-value') // compatible with all browsers and also the most performance efficient. See benchmark below
    // Or .. $(this).data('value')
    // Or .. this.data.value
}
```

**[Benchmark Test](http://jsperf.com/jquery-data-value-vs-getattribute)** Courtesy of @crush

Comment: `$(this).data("value")` looks better in my opinion

Comment: What's the browser support on `this.dataset`? [Take a look here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.dataset).

Comment: All [current](http://caniuse.com/#search=dataset) browsers. That's why I gave the other option of using jQuery.

Comment: @dcodesmith why not use `this.getAttribute('data-value');` as the other option. Unless he's doing more with `this` that necessitates it being a jQuery object, it's a waste to make it into a jQuery object simply to retrieve an attribute.

Comment: Up to the OP TBH. If he's supporting old browsers then he can use it.

Comment: @dcodesmith It's a better use of resources than `$(this).data('value')` (which is your older browser solution). Doesn't matter anyways as he's accepted a wrong answer.

Comment: I delete mine and +1 yours. At least other people who come here should realize that the accepted answer is wrong based on the vote total. [**Here is a benchmark of the three methods**](http://jsperf.com/jquery-data-value-vs-getattribute)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
console.log(this.getAttribute("value"));
```

but as has been noted, a table row isn't supposed to have a value attribute.

Comment: But a Table TD supports that though

Comment: Not officially. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
console.log($(this).prop("value"));
```

Comment: This solution still returned undefined